# FB.api wallpost link URL changes when it contains Facebooks TLD

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps

Hi Im using this script to post:

```
postToFb:function () {
    //alert(window.FbPostParameters.link);
    FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', window.FbPostParameters, function (response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
            console.log('/me/feed - Error occured');
        } else {
            console.log('/me/feed - Published to stream!');
        }
    });
},
```

And alerted `window.FbPostParameters.link` is:

**http://www.facebook.com/FBPAGENAME/app_APPID?app_data=forum**

Its funny, cuz when I checked the wallpost the url has become this:

**http://www.facebook.com/FBPAGENAME?ref=hl&sk=app_APPID%26app_data%3Dforum**

The problem is that the posted url is fully functional (and fb passes app_data to application)  but the latter one is not working. Not even renders the application tab until I remove the **%26app_data%3Dforum** part.

I could not find any resource to debug this problem. Can you help me?

ps: encodeURI or encodeURIcomponent results the same.

**UPDATE:** link to example: http://www.facebook.com/kenivajszmuller/app_238038449651632

Can anyone help? ty

Comment: Dear Claudiu! I cant fully understand you. According your profile you are a Facebook developer or something like that. I wrote my code as-is in the Facebook SDK doc says. But its not results what it should. I've spent 6+ hours to debug this problem and you send me a link how to ask questions? ty. honestly.

Comment: That is exactly why I'm asking you what have you tried? People want to help, but need more details to locate the issue. If you read that article you'll see that it's well intended. I posted this as a comment for the exact same reason, to help you improve your question; at the moment, it's hard to follow. What have you tried looking at before asking here?

Comment: I've tried to post the link as the converted style: http://www.facebook.com/FBPAGENAME?ref=hl&sk=app_APPID&app_data=forum but it resulted http://www.facebook.com/FBPAGENAME?ref=hl&sk=app_APPID without the app_data part. And because of it happens only with 'facebook.com/*' domains I think there can be a converting method while posting it (which for example puts ref=hl parameters in it).

Comment: Both URLs you mentioned should work. They work for me too, so I can't replicate. Did you try looking at your app and seeing if you're handling some params wrong? "The problem is that the posted url is fully functional (and fb passes app_data to application) but the latter one is not working. Not even renders the application tab until I remove the %26app_data%3Dforum part." Did you try both `http` and `https`? It's close to impossible to help you debug, without you having dug a bit more before posting or giving us some guidance...

Comment: An actual link to the app can also help!

Comment: Ty, tomorrow I'll try to create a public sample showing the issue. :)

Comment: Thanks, just ping this thread when you do.

Comment: question updated with live demo

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16585/discussion-between-zsitro-and-claudiu)

Comment: Hi @zsitro - I'm getting "$ undefined" for `$('#btn1').on('click',function(){..` - can you please review your code?

Comment: you have used https and the jquery was forced to load with http. Now you can test it  both way. :)